# Error (10327) can't determine definition of operator ""=""

Tags: vhdl

For this VHDL design description:

```
library ieee;
     use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
     use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity four_bit_counter is
    port (
        count_out : out unsigned (3 downto 0);
        clk : in std_logic;
        enable:in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic) ;
    end four_bit_counter;
    
architecture arc of four_bit_counter is
    signal count : unsigned (3 downto 0);
    begin
        process (clk, reset, enable)
            begin
                if (reset = '1') then
                count <= "0000";
            elsif (clk' event and clk = '1') then
                if (enable = '1') then
                    if (count="1010") then
                    count<="0000";
                    else
                        count <= count +1;
                end if;
            end ;
        end if;
    end process;
            count_out <= count;
            end arc;
```

I have the error

```
Error (10327): VHDL error at four_bit_counter.vhd(22): can't determine definition of operator ""="" -- found 2 possible definitions
```

and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Use a qualified expression to explicitly provide the type of the right operand: `if count = unsigned'("1010") then`. Otherwise you could use package numeric_std which doesn't support "=" [unsigned, signed return boolean].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two possible definitions are both from package std_logic_arith

```vhdl
function "="(L: UNSIGNED; R: UNSIGNED) return BOOLEAN;
function "="(L: SIGNED; R: UNSIGNED) return BOOLEAN;
```

The ambiguity comes from overload resolution for the equality operator due to the package providing the second definition and how the type of the right operand a string literal is determined.

See IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.2 Literals:

> String and bit string literals are representations of one-dimensional arrays of characters. The type of a string or bit string literal shall be determinable solely from the context in which the literal appears, excluding the literal itself but using the fact that the type of the literal shall be a one-dimensional array of a character type. The lexical structure of string and bit string literals is defined in Clause 15.

Here the context is the equality operator, where 12.5 The context of overload resolution specifies the error:

> Overloading is defined for names, subprograms, and enumeration literals.
>
> For overloaded entities, overload resolution determines the actual meaning that an occurrence of an identifier or a character literal has whenever the visibility rules have determined that more than one meaning is acceptable at the place of this occurrence; overload resolution likewise determines the actual meaning of an occurrence of an operator or basic operation (see 5.1).
>
> At such a place, all visible declarations are considered. The occurrence is only legal if there is exactly one interpretation of each constituent of the innermost *complete context*. ...

Overloads for operators are provided by function declarations (
4.5.2 Operator overloading). For a binary operator the left operand is association with the first function parameter and the right parameter is associated with the second parameter. The return value is a Boolean (again from context, it's an if statement's condition which is a Boolean expression).

The type of the right operand can't be determined from context.

There are several possible solutions

1. Use the IEEE's numeric_std package instead where functions implementing operators don't have both signed and unsigned operands. Package numeric_std is incorporated into the standard's -2008 revision leading to package std_logic_arith's eventual deprecation.
2. Use a qualified expression (9.3.5) to specifically state the type of the operand.

```vhdl
        if count = unsigned'("1010") then
```

(the redundant parentheses around the condition have been removed for clarity)

3. Rely on an abstract literal (15.5) where the ambiguity doesn't exist. This can either be of the form of a decimal literal (15.5.2) or based literal (15.5.3).
4. Use a function call to the overloaded operator's declaration with a selected name noting that named association can't be used for operator overloads.
5. Define an object (here a constant) with that value provided by a value expression. The type is inherent in an object declaration.